# Classnames not working with SASS Modules in Preact

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, preact

I'm running into a classnames issue with sass modules in Preact:

```
// Card component
import { h, Component } from "preact";
import cx from "classnames";
import style from "./style";

export const Card = () => {
  return (
    <div class={style.card}>
      <div class={cx(style.image, "image-item")} />
      <div class={style.body} />
    </div>
  );
};

// in style.scss
.card {
  .image-item {
    margin-bottom: 23px;
  }
}
```

The specified margin-bottom css does not get applied, any ideas?

Comment: For starters, you need to use `className` instead of `class`

Comment: @Paras it is okay to use `class` in Preact, it's not React. See [Preact Doc](https://preactjs.com/guide/differences-to-react)

Comment: Whoops, my bad :)